# Is there an affordable alternative to AWS elastic transcoder?

Tags: amazon-web-services, transcoding, amazon-elastic-transcoder

I am working on a project that would require the use of video / media transcoding , however I am on a budget and AWS transcoder seems a bit expensive for me at the moment, so I would like to know if there's a more affordable alternative to AWS elastic transcoder?

Comment: If folks are interested in creating a venue for these types of questions, follow the proposal for a [dedicated Cloud Computing site on StackExchange](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/110490/cloud-computing-aws-azure-google-openstack-etc?referrer=Gtut7wQSWPk88jFJz_zqMg2) and up-vote some sample questions.

Answer (score 1):

AWS Elastic Transcoder is definitely one of the most affordable video transcoding solutions out there.

One of the key selling points is that you only pay for *actual usage*, e.g. no minimum fees etc.

If you face a *huge* amount of video material to transcode and are not afraid of setting up your own media encoder, you can go with a [rails app](http://rubyonrails.org/) using [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) and [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) / [libAV](https://www.libav.org/) and a reasonable job queue, e.g. [Delayed Job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) or [Resque](https://github.com/resque/resque).
This could be hosted e.g. on [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/).